# scrolltop to specific position

Tags: javascript

the following is the code I have for scrollTop function. It only scrolls the div to the top, but I want the div to be 300px down from the top. can anyone help?

```
$(function() {
$("#button").on("click", function() {
    $("html, body"). animate({"scrollTop":$("#div").offset().top}, 1000);
    return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: `$("#div").offset().top + 300`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("html, body"). animate({"scrollTop":$("#div").offset().top - 300}, 1000);
```

Comment: If i subtract 300 px from the top location of the div, I get a location thats 300 px above the div. Subtracting 300 is absolutely correct.

Comment: @Mesaph yes,it is absolutely correct. thank you very much for responding.